# Insert tall image in one page

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I have a very tall image (591 x 8383) which I want to put as Appendix in my Latex document. How can I place this picture vertically aligned on a single (really big) page?

I have tried

```
\includepdf[fitpaper]{images/ctt2.pdf}
```

This just shows the complete image scaled down so it fits on one standard latex page. 
If i try it without the fitpaper argument it is the size it should be but it gets cut off at the point where it would go beyond one page.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the `graphicx` package and then in the line where you want to insert the file, write: `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{images/ctt2.pdf}` that should help you with the size of the image.

Comment: @Aradnix if I understand the OP right, he does not want to scale the picture, but to produce and oversized page?

Comment: @greyshade That's right, and I was thinking also in the `KOMAscript` bundle for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly and you want to change the page size for one page to fit the image onto it, there's two options documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812892/change-paper-size-in-the-middle-of-a-latex-document).

They basically are using one of the KOMA (`scr`) classes and using:

```
\KOMAoptions{paper=a3}
\recalctypearea
```

or (if using `pdflatex` only) changing page dimensions with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Normal page
\eject \pdfpagewidth=3in \pdfpageheight=10in

Tall page
\eject \pdfpagewidth=10in \pdfpageheight=3in

Wide page
\end{document}
```